# Mocking FirstOrDefault in rhino mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to mock the following stuff:

```
_reportsRepo.Expect(x => x.Table.FirstOrDefault(s => s.MessageId == 1)).Return(new Report { Id = 1 });
```

but i get ArgumentNullException.
Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you mocking?  The Table context?  In addition, there's no good reason to mock `FirstOrDefault'.  It simply takes the first or default in a collection, so you should simply be returning a single object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just do something along these lines:

```
_reportsRepo.Expect(x => x.Table).Return(new []{Report { Id = 1 }});
```

depending on exactly what type Table is.

you can't mock `FirstOrDefault` instead you should mock the enumeration which it is returning so that it returns a collection which fulfils your requirements

Comment: thnx, in my case it looks like 
`_reportsRepo.Expect(x => x.Table).Return(new List<Report> {new Report { MessageId = 1 }}.AsQueryable());`